# Could this nested class cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, android

This is a learning exercise for me at the moment because what I'll end up doing is creating one `GestureListener` object and re-assigning it to all new `MyTouchView` objects.

(For Brevity, I've omitted some necessary bits of code.)

**Question is:** for the code below, would the (possibly) many  `GestureListener` objects be prevented from finalizing ? As you can see, a lot of `GestureListener` objects would be created - one for each time the user flips through a page.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity

    // Widgets
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TextView mTVPageCount;
    private TextView mTVTitle;
    private Button mBShare;
    private Button mBBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTVPageCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pagecount);
        mTVTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mBShare = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        mBBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
    }

    private class TouchAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        //pre-create neighboring views
        @Override
        public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                MyTouchView img = new MyTouchView(container.getContext());
                img.setOnDoubleTapListener(new GestureListener());
                return img;
        }
    }

    private class GestureListener implements GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            int iVisibility = mTVPageCount.getVisibility();
            int iNewVisibility;
            if (iVisibility == View.VISIBLE) {
                iNewVisibility = View.GONE;
            } else {
                iNewVisibility = View.VISIBLE;
            }
            mTVPageCount.setVisibility(iNewVisibility);
            mTVTitle.setVisibility(iNewVisibility);
            mBShare.setVisibility(iNewVisibility);
            mBBack.setVisibility(iNewVisibility);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the above code work? When do you attach the `img` to the container? Do you implement `destroyItem`?

Comment: `img` is returned, so it is the container. `destroyItem` is implemented and it is just `container.removeView((View) object);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ,your code should be Ok.

All your non-static inner class(`GestureListener` and `TouchAdapter`) will have an implicit reference to your `Activity`, but they do not have a longer life cycle than the `Activity`, hence when your `Activity` is destroyed, listeners can be garbage-collected as a whole.

Some other listeners held by the process may have the memory leaks,which you should take more care of,  say `LocationListener` , so if you do not unregister it by your own, it will remain registered, and if you declare it as non-static inner class, which may leak the memory.

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok.

PagerView doesn't reuse the old view, but always keep a small amount of views in memory, which will be enough to show and cache. You can use `setOffscreenPageLimit` to adjust the number.

---